# find_package falha ao gerar projeto (em Qt) com CMake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt, cmake

Eu estou tentando gerar a configuração de compilação de um exemplo simples em Qt usando CMake. O código do exemplo é esse:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.setText("Olá mundo!");
    textEdit.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

E o arquivo de configuração do CMake é esse:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project (teste)

# Configuracao do Qt
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Configuracao especifica para o gcc
if(NOT WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -g")
endif()

# Adiciona todos os fontes na variavel SRCS
file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp *.h)

# Nome do executavel
if(WIN32)
    add_executable(teste WIN32 ${SRCS})
else()
    add_executable(teste ${SRCS})
endif()

# Usa os modulos do Qt 5
target_link_libraries(teste Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(teste Qt5::Widgets)
```

Quando eu gero a configuração no Windows (v.10, 64bits), vai de boa. Porém, quando eu faço o mesmo no Ubuntu (v.14.04, 32bits), o CMake produz a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):    By not providing
>   "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has    asked
>   CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but 
>   CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core"
>   with any    of the following names:
>
> ```
>  Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
>  qt5core-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set    "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
>   If    "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
>   sure it has    been installed.

Algumas informações adicionais:

- O Qt 5.5.1 está corretamente instalado no Ubuntu (na pasta local `/home/luiz/Qt5.5.1`).
- Executando o comando `apt-file search Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`, eu obtenho o seguinte path: `qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`. Assim, já tentei adicionar `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/cmake/` à variável de ambiente `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (conforme orienta [a documentação](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) no 5º parágrafo de *Getting Started*), mas o erro continua.
- Eu só não tentei definir individualmente as variáveis `Qt5<Module>_DIR` porque eu acredito que essa abordagem só irá dar mais trabalho do que o necessário (e talvez exista alguma outra configuração errada).

Alguém sabe onde eu possa estar errando?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Foi normal. Realmente não tem no apt, [o tutorial de instalação](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu) usa diretamente o download do site. Por isso eu creio que foi instalado na pasta local (mas não imaginei que isso seria possivelmente um problema). Sobre o resto, sim, estava errado na pergunta. Vou corrigir. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não. Eu instalei a 5.5.1 mesmo. :) (o tutorial de instalação é um pouco mais antigo rs). Só no windows que eu instalei a 5.6 (mas por uma questão de dependência do VS 2015 - lá tá funcionando de boa).

Comment: Chegou a tentar isto http://askubuntu.com/q/374755/181632 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu já tinha visto essa pergunta (aliás, achei a dica do `apt-file` lá). Mas admito que a resposta aceita é um pouco confusa pra mim. Cheguei a tentar mudar os nomes dos pacotes no `find_package` como sugere (no padrão "qt*5-dev"), mas se for isso também não funcionou aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu tentei também (pensando a mesma coisa que vc). Só que ai ele dá o mesmo erro no Widgets. :/

Comment: Chegou a reinstalar o cmake `apt-get remove cmake & apt-get install cmake`? Talvez falte algo, já que o apt-search encontra mas o cmake não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não, isso eu não fiz. Farei agora depois do almoço.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acabei de reinstalar o CMake, e o erro continua. :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pela ajuda. Mas eu consegui resolver (vide minha resposta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver com ajuda [dessa outra thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633826/default-installation-prefix-qt5-qt5-widgets-ubuntu). Haviam dois problemas:

1. Ao invés de definir o caminho em uma variável `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` de ambiente, parece que o "mais correto" é fazer como uma variável dentro do script CMake.
2. O caminho correto é mesmo a instalação do Qt, mas incluindo a especificação do compilador (no caso do Ubuntu, o gcc).

Assim, eu só adicionei o seguinte trecho ao meu script CMake, *antes de chamar o `find_package`*:

```
if(WIN32)
    set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\Qt5.6.0\\5.6\\msvc2015\\")
elseif(UNIX)
    set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc/)
endif()
```

A definição da variável `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` não foi necessária no meu ambiente Windows anteriormente porque o caminho do Qt se encontrava adicionado ao Path. Assim, para evitar essa configuração específica dentro do arquivo de script CMake, **o mais indicado** é adicionar o caminho de instalação do Qt à variável `PATH` do ambiente (tanto no Windows como no Linux) e não utilizar a variável `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Comment: Imaginei algo assim, só que o problema é que pra diferentes "pessoas" isso não vai compilar né? Mas como não sei bem qual seu objetivo me parece que atende a sua necessidade atual +1 ;)

Comment: É, mas pelo menos outra pessoa com o problema similar vai ter alguma dica mais objetiva de como proceder (já que a documentação não é lá muito clara). :)

Comment: Entendi, uma curiosidade, se esta usando QT porque não usa o arquivo `.pro`? Por exemplo cria o projeto e cria um .bat e um bash dentro da pasta do projeto, que rodaria os seguintes comando `qmake` e `make && make install`? Sei que o Cmake é mais pra "preparar" o ambiente, mas no seu caso me parece uma tentativa de compilar, estou enganado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Boa curiosidade. :) Eu já usava o `.pro` dessa forma (tenho até um script bacana que é tanto batch como bash pra gerar os arquivos do VS no Windows e o Makefile no Ubuntu). Acontece que recentemente eu precisei usar o CMake por causa de umas dependências adicionais. Resumidamente, o `.pro` facilita a minha vida no caso do Qt, mas não tem facilitado muito no caso do OpenCV e das demais dependências.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eis o tal script bacana. :) https://github.com/luigivieira/F3/blob/master/fat/update_projects.cmd

Comment: ah entendo, mas você compilar o OpenVC junto ao QT? Ou você pré-compila o OpenVC e depois "linka" no teu projeto? Porque poderia fazer duas coisas separadas talvez, é que o QT é muito chato as vezes de instalar e também vivo tendo dificuldades no Linux devido a isso. Então sempre me mantenho no `qmake`. Vou dar uma olhado no teu projeto.

Comment: Ah entendi, você compila algumas coisas pelo MSVC direto, por isso estranhei, é que eu uso só o QT mesmo e não uso o .sln, no caso é o .pro mesmo (geralmente uso o IDE do QT mesmo).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pois é, eu tive a impressão de que o CMake talvez ajudaria com essas dificuldades futuras (principalmente com as novas dependências que vão entrar agora). Mas vamos ver. Na prática estou aprendendo a usá-lo mesmo. Mas vou manter o `qmake` à mão da mesma forma. Valeu! :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, no Windows eu uso direto o MSVC. Questão de costume. rs

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz uma edição na resposta, porque basta adicionar o caminho do Qt ao path para não precisar da variável `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. :)

Comment: Sabe que pensei isso, por isso havia perguntando como fez a instalação, acho estranho o instalador do QT não ter feito esse processo pra ti.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pois é. Só descobri quando fui rodar o qmake e não achou no path. :/